# ng-repeat to create a multiple-nested table

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a table of the following structure:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>Column 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="singleArray in groupOfArrays">
        <tr>
            <td>{{calcTotalObj(singleArray).x}}</td>
            <td>{{calcTotalObj(singleArray).y}}</td>
            <td>{{calcTotalObj(singleArray).z}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in singleArray"> <!-- scope of item starts here -->
            <td style='padding-left:30px;'>{{item.x}}</td>
            <td>{{item.y}}</td>
            <td>{{item.z}}</td>
        </tr> <!-- scope of item ends here -->
        <!-- here is where I want to add the row I describe below -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

(Note: When I say "nesting" below, I don't mean nesting in the actual "table within a table" sense, as I want it to look like the rows fit together, not multiple tables within each other)

However, I need to add an additional level of nesting below the second row in the `tbody`. I don't think there's any HTML that's allowed, and just adding another row of the form:

```
<tr ng-repeat="nest in item">
    <td style='padding=left:50px'>
........
</tr>
```

Doesn't work, because I'm no longer inside the previous row to make use of the loop variable `item`.

How can I add this additional level of nesting? Or should I restructure?

EDIT: Structure of `groupOfArrays`

```
groupOfArrays = 
{ array[
    obj = { x=1,y=2, z=4 }
   ,obj2 = { x=3, y=6, z=8 }
   ,obj3 = { x=5, y=9, z=3 }
   ]
}
```

So `calcTotalObj()` (which I realize I left out before) will calculate the total of a value in the internal objects (say, `x`, in the above example). It will return an object of the same type but with the values totaled. The second row will be a drilldown of the above row, and will be repeated for all values in the groupOfArrays. The row I want to add will be a further drilldown.

Comment: I'd imagine you have to restructure - like you said, you're no longer in `singleArray` scope, so the reference to `item` is lost.. can you post your data structure?

Comment: Doesn't work, because I'm no longer inside the previous row to make use of the loop variable item. I don't see any scope referred to "item", can you elaborate more?

Comment: I've tried to understand, but didn't get what you want to do.

Comment: @jack.the.ripper I edited the code in the question to have comments where I want to add the additional row and where the scope of `item` is restricted to.

Comment: @rar can you please add your groupOfArrays to question ?

Comment: @sylwester I've adjusted the code as I realized one part that was unclear.

Comment: @RafaelEyng I've edited my code in the question, please see again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ng-repeat-start`, `ng-repeat-end` basic sample below

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('homeCtrl', function ($scope) {


    $scope.data = [{
        id: "1a",
        name: "apple"
    }, {
        id: "2a",
        name: "pear"
    }, {
        id: "3a",
        name: "banana"
    }];

    
   




});
```

```css
tr.border_bottom td {
  border-bottom:1pt solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

 <div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="homeCtrl">
      
      <table>
        <tr ng-repeat-start="item in data" class="border_bottom"><td>{{$index}}</td><td>{{item.id}}</td></tr>
        <tr ng-repeat-end class="border_bottom"><td></td><td>{{item.name}}</td></tr>
      </table>


    
      
      
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Words do not describe how much this has helped me.  Thank you so much!